# Logging fails sometimes when program is run as system user from a systemd service. As root always works

Tags: python, logging, systemd

I have a system user account called `user` created like this:

```
useradd -r user
```

I have a very simple Python program which logs just one line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import logging
import os

# Set logging options
logging.basicConfig(level=os.environ.get("LOGLEVEL", "INFO"))

logging.info('LOG SOMETHING')
```

And I have a `systemd` service to run that Python program:

```
[Unit]
Description=Run simple.py

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/simple.py
User=user
```

If I run the Python program from the command line, with both `root` and `user` users, it works just fine:

```
# /usr/local/bin/simple.py 
INFO:root:LOG SOMETHING
# runuser -l user -c '/usr/local/bin/simple.py' 
runuser: warning: cannot change directory to /home/user: No such file or directory
INFO:root:LOG SOMETHING
```

Ignore that warning. That's because the system user account `user` doesn't have a home directory.

Now, if I run the `systemd` service as the `user` user (note the `User=user` at the end of the service file), the logging sometimes fails, sometimes doesn't fail:

```
# systemctl start simple.service
# systemctl start simple.service
# systemctl start simple.service
# systemctl start simple.service
# systemctl start simple.service
# systemctl start simple.service
# journalctl -u simple.service | tail -18
Dec 08 17:57:23 localhost systemd[1]: Starting Run simple.py...
Dec 08 17:57:23 localhost systemd[1]: Started Run simple.py.
Dec 08 17:57:24 localhost systemd[1]: Starting Run simple.py...
Dec 08 17:57:24 localhost systemd[1]: Started Run simple.py.
Dec 08 17:57:25 localhost systemd[1]: Starting Run simple.py...
Dec 08 17:57:25 localhost systemd[1]: Started Run simple.py.
Dec 08 17:57:25 localhost systemd[1]: Starting Run simple.py...
Dec 08 17:57:25 localhost systemd[1]: Started Run simple.py.
Dec 08 17:57:26 localhost systemd[1]: Starting Run simple.py...
Dec 08 17:57:26 localhost simple.py[12774]: INFO:root:LOG SOMETHING
Dec 08 17:57:26 localhost systemd[1]: Started Run simple.py.
Dec 08 17:57:27 localhost systemd[1]: Starting Run simple.py...
Dec 08 17:57:27 localhost systemd[1]: Started Run simple.py.
```

Now, if I run the `systemd` service as the `root` user (just removing the `User=user` at the end of the service file, and of course running `systemctl daemon-reload`), the logging **always** works:

```
# systemctl start simple.service
# journalctl -u simple.service | tail -18
Dec 08 18:04:03 localhost systemd[1]: Starting Run simple.py...
Dec 08 18:04:03 localhost simple.py[12827]: INFO:root:LOG SOMETHING
Dec 08 18:04:03 localhost systemd[1]: Started Run simple.py.
Dec 08 18:04:03 localhost systemd[1]: Starting Run simple.py...
Dec 08 18:04:03 localhost simple.py[12835]: INFO:root:LOG SOMETHING
Dec 08 18:04:03 localhost systemd[1]: Started Run simple.py.
Dec 08 18:04:04 localhost systemd[1]: Starting Run simple.py...
Dec 08 18:04:04 localhost simple.py[12843]: INFO:root:LOG SOMETHING
Dec 08 18:04:04 localhost systemd[1]: Started Run simple.py.
Dec 08 18:04:05 localhost systemd[1]: Starting Run simple.py...
Dec 08 18:04:05 localhost simple.py[12851]: INFO:root:LOG SOMETHING
Dec 08 18:04:05 localhost systemd[1]: Started Run simple.py.
Dec 08 18:04:05 localhost systemd[1]: Starting Run simple.py...
Dec 08 18:04:05 localhost simple.py[12859]: INFO:root:LOG SOMETHING
Dec 08 18:04:05 localhost systemd[1]: Started Run simple.py.
Dec 08 18:04:06 localhost systemd[1]: Starting Run simple.py...
Dec 08 18:04:06 localhost simple.py[12867]: INFO:root:LOG SOMETHING
Dec 08 18:04:06 localhost systemd[1]: Started Run simple.py.
```

Why is that?

Comment: What OS/`systemd` version do you have? I can't reproduce this on `CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)`, `systemd 219`. Copied your script/service file, started with: `# for (( i=1; i<=1000; i++)); do systemctl start simple; sleep 1; done`. Checked with: `# journalctl -u simple --since "2017-12-8 19:52:00" | grep "LOG SOMETHING" | wc -l`, got 1000 back. Also got exactly 1000 service starts: `# journalctl -u simple --since "2017-12-8 19:52:00" | grep "Executing: /usr/local/bin/simple.py" | wc -l`

Comment: `CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)` with `systemd-219-42.el7_4.4.x86_64`.